# SwiftUI - fullScreenCover not working on iOS 14.4.2

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to swiftUI. I publish an app to the App Store it's working fine but some of iOS it isn't working properly. may be **fullScreenCover** not working  that's way `MathPlayingHistoryView`   not appearing when user **tap** on the `refreshdButtonSmall()` .bellow code.

```
   refreshdButtonSmall()
  .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$lovePresent) {
            MathPlayingHistoryView(isPresented: $lovePresent)
        }
     .onTapGesture{
          withAnimation(.spring(response:0.2,dampingFraction:0.5,blendDuration:0)){
             lovePresent.toggle()
          }
     }
```

Update:

```
public struct refreshdButtonSmall: View {
    var imageName = "star"

    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(systemName: imageName)
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

Device information:
Divice : XR 
iOS : 14.4.2

Would you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: share code of `refreshdButtonSmall`

Comment: @RomaKavinskyi updated code check please

Comment: You shared a structure. Share a function `refreshdButtonSmall()`, please

Comment: @RomaKavinskyi `refreshdButtonSmall()` is a SwiftUI view, and it's already included in OP's question.

Comment: @EricAya please help me to remove the issue. due to this issue I losing every day  very number of user

Comment: I've seen a similar problem with only on iOS 14.4 devices but it was working on before and after version like 14.3 or 14.5. We don't have any solution or info about the cause tho.